# Primitive types pass template parameter between c++ and CLI

Tags: templates, c++-cli

I have a c++ templated class:

```
template<class T>
class A {
    void test (T temp) { }
};
```

But i need to wrap it in CLI so it can be used in c#.

Example:

CLI:

```
template<class T>
ref class AWrap {
     private:
        A* a;
     public:
        void test (T temp) { 
           a->test<T>(temp);
        }
};
```

C#:

```
Awrap blah = new AWrap();
blah<int>(3);
```

If I make a CLI templated `ref class` , which call the templated c++ method, will the primitive types generate the right c++ templated code on compilation ?->

Comment: Even your C++ code seems wrong here -- you're trying to pass template parameters to a member function that isn't a template (it's a non-template member of a template class).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are using in C# are generics, not templates. There is no way of specializing a C++/CLI template from C#.

Comment: Thanks, but if I'd declare the CLI as generic<>, rather than template<>, will that work ?

Comment: No, because the template will be specialized at compile time, where as generics are specialized at run-time. So by the time you compiled your C++/CLI code, there is no template code left. You could create explicit template specializations while compiling, but they will not be accessible from C#. Basically, you'll have to rewrite your C++ template code from scratch as C++/CLI generics (or directly in C#).