# Wrapping native C++ templated class with C++/CLI

Tags: c++, templates, c++-cli

Is it possible to wrap a templated native C++ class with C++/CLI? For example,

```
template <class T>
class TemplateTest
{
public:
    TemplateTest(const T& x) { mX = x; }
    ~TemplateTest(void);

    T getValue() { return mX; }
private:

    T mX;
};
```

The usual way is to hold a pointer to class `TemplateTest` however with a templated class I would have to know what type T is at compile time. How do people normally manage these kinds of scenarios?

Comment: Just found this related question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735507/primitive-types-pass-template-parameter-between-c-and-cli. However, that answer does not provide a strategy to deal with the problem.

Comment: Sorry seth, I've voted to close this as an exact duplicate of 4735507. That answer does not provide a strategy for dealing with the problem because there is no general strategy, other than pre-defining all such template specialisations you care about, and explicitly mapping each CLI generic to a custom wrapper for the template specialisation.

Comment: OK well your comment answers my question. I was hoping someone had an innovative way of dealing with it that I had not thought of. You could put your comment as the answer. Not to fussed if you close it either.

Comment: Since templates are a compile-time construct, you'd have to know what `T` is at compile time in every usage of the class. That's just how templates work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general strategy, other than pre-defining all such template specialisations you care about, and explicitly mapping each CLI generic to a custom wrapper for the template specialisation.